# Laravel 5.4 - Updating a File record

Tags: php, model-view-controller, laravel-5.4

I'm pretty new to Laravel, thus I'm trying to learn some of the basics. I have managed to create a CRUD with file upload. What I did was I created a resource controller. My store method:

```
public function store(Request $request) {

        $this->validate($request, [
            'name' => 'required',
            'avatar' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg',
            'boat_type' => 'required',
            'rooms' => 'required',
            'price_per_hour' => 'required',
            'price' => 'required',
        ]);
        $boat = new Boat($request->input()) ;
            if($file = $request->hasFile('avatar')) {
                $file = $request->file('avatar') ;
                $fileName = $file->getClientOriginalName() ;
                $destinationPath = public_path().'/img/boats/avatars/' ;
                $file->move($destinationPath,$fileName);
                $boat->avatar = $fileName ;
            }
            $boat->save() ;
            return redirect()->route('management.index')
                        ->with('success','New Boat Successfully Added!');
    }
```

This method works perfectly fine, with this I am able to upload and store the details to my database and am able to manipulate it in my view.

But when I try to use the UPDATE method I have the exact code.. yet when I try to update my post everything can be updated except my avatar variable. it updates it but it stores it in a strange format. Here is my UPDATE method

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'name' => 'required',
            'boat_type' => 'required',
            'rooms' => 'required',
            'price_per_hour' => 'required',
            'price' => 'required',
        ]);

        $boat = Boat::find($id);
      if($file = $request->hasFile('avatar')) {
                $file = $request->file('avatar') ;
                $fileName = $file->getClientOriginalName() ;
                $destinationPath = public_path().'/img/boats/avatars/' ;
                $file->move($destinationPath,$fileName);
                $boat->avatar = $fileName ;
            }
            $boat->save() ;
        $boat_update = $request->all();
        $boat->update($boat_update);
        $request->session()->flash('alert-success', 'Boat Successfully Updated!');
        return redirect('/management');
    }
```

When I edit the avatar variable it stores it in `/img/boats/avatars/C:\xampp\tmp\phpFA50.tmp`

I'm not really sure what is wrong. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

1. `$boat->save() ;` you don't need to save before update -> remove it
2. `$boat_update = $request->all();` -> Your filename is NOT in there
3. `$boat->update($boat_update);` Are all the fields `$fillable`? If yes you need to add the new filename to that array

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution, it was pretty much a logic error as I was simply saving the file name then overwriting it with the `$request->all()`

The correct solution would be this:

```
$boat = Boat::find($id);
$boat->fill($request->except('avatar'));
if($file = $request->hasFile('avatar')) {
    $file = $request->file('avatar') ;
    $fileName = $file->getClientOriginalName() ;
    $destinationPath = public_path().'/img/boats/avatars/' ;
    $file->move($destinationPath,$fileName);
    $boat->avatar = $fileName ;
}
$boat->save();

$request->session()->flash('alert-success', 'Boat Successfully Updated!');
return redirect('/management');`
```